# Access a jupyter notebook from other device

Tags: python-3.x, networking, jupyter-notebook

When I run jupyter notebook command it starts a server program on 8888 port of localhost. Now, how can I access the notebook on some other device? Let's say I am connected to wifi and my ip address is xx.xx.xx.xx which is available from the output of ifconfig command. Now if I try to access xx.xx.xx.xx:8888 from another device, ain't I supposed to access the notebooks? I am also providing the security token available in the output if jupyter notebook command.
What am I missing?

Comment: you aint........

Answer (score 0):

It just listens by default to ip `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` start it with [1] it will then listen on all interfaces.

[1]

```
$ jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0
```